# Finite element method for quasilinear parabolic PDE

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I have a quasilinear parabolic PDE like this:
$H_t=(a-bH^{1/3})H_{xx}+(c+1/3bH^{-2/3}+bH^{1/3})H_x$
with standard homogeneous BC and IC.
What methods can you suggest to solve it numerically?
Is it possible to solve it with simple FEM directly?
I tried mixed FEM, but i can not implement it due to 1/3 degrees.
I found another methods like $H^1$ Galerkin method and collocation FEM that can be used in order to solve it. Do you have some ideas?